# App That stays even after Hard reset

Tags: java, android, reset

Am planning to develop a new AntiTheft Android application and i would like to keep my app even after hard reset so people can access the phone remotely even after culprit resetting it.

I have made some research regarding this but answers are not clear, can anybody help me here?

Comment: This is impossible unless the app is installed in the system partition. Apps installed by the user are in the user data partition. Getting a third-party app to be installed in the system partition is something an ordinary user with an ordinary device (or rather, a stock OS) would not be able to do.

Comment: Is it possible with rooted phones?

Comment: In theory yes, though I don't know exactly to do that.